# Trying to pass a prop through <Route /> or <Link />

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass a prop through Router and have tried multiple solutions, all of which pass an empty prop.

I was initially trying to pass the match object to access the URL parameters but I have resolved to pass something...anything at this point.

Using *react-router-dom* which is router v4 I think.
Also I am correctly importing anything relevant here in `SearchArtist.js`

```
 import ArtistDetails from './ArtistDetails'
 import {
     BrowserRouter,
     Route,
     Link
 } from 'react-router-dom'
```

### This is `ArtistDetails.js` it is unchanged through all 3 attempts

`ArtistDetails.js`

```
class ArtistDetailsComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props)
    }

    render() {
        <div></div>
    }
}
```

### I have tried:

## Attempt 1# - Using render in Route

`SearchArtist.js`

```
<Link to='/artist'>

<Route path='/artist' render={(props) => (
    <ArtistDetails something='hello' {...props} />
)} />
```

Console log in `ArtistDetails.js` returns empty props

## Attempt 2# - Passing object to Link

`SearchArtist.js`

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/artist', state: { foo: 'bar'} }}>
     {item.longTitle}
</Link>

<Route path='/artist' component={ArtistDetails}/>
```

Console log in `ArtistDetails.js` returns empty props

## Attempt 3# - Using params in Link

`SearchArtist.js`

```
<Link to='/artist' params={{ something: 'hello' }}>
     {item.longTitle}
</Link>

<Route path='/artist' component={ArtistDetails}/>
```

Console log in `ArtistDetails.js` returns empty props

I receive no errors, anything in render() works I am simply unable to pass any information to my class. This is my first solo React project and I don't know if I am missing something fundamental.

### Solution

I tried replicating the error in a simpler project and couldn't, found out it was how I was exporting the components.

I changed

```
export default function ArtistDetails(){
    return (
        <ArtistDetailsComp />
    )
}
```

to just

```
export default ArtistDetails
```

then renamed the class from `ArtistDetailsComp` to ArtistDetails`` and it worked.

---

```
export default function ArtistDetails(props){
    return (
        <ArtistDetailsComp props={props} />
    )
}
```

This also works, turns out I wasn't passing props through at all in the export, so when I was calling props, obviously nothing was available, hopefully this helps someone else later on.

Comment: The file name `ArtistDetails.js` and class name `ArtistDetailsComp ` calling name `<ArtistDetails /> ` makes no matching here.

Comment: True it is strange, I will change it in my file

Answer (score 0):

i hope this would help,

try writing `render()`,

```
<Route path="/artist" render={() => <ArtistDetails newProps={this.props} />} />
```

try using `component`,

```
<Route path="/artist" component={() => <ArtistDetails newProps={this.props} />} />
```

Its Passing Props Down To React-Router Route,

```
<Route
  path="/artist"
  render={(routeProps) => (
    <ArtistDetails {...routeProps} {...props} />
  )}
/>
```

using new update its directly possible,

```
<Route path="/artist" render={(props) => <ArtistDetails {...props} />} />

class ArtistDetails extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried every variation of your suggestions. Unfortunately still same result.

Comment: Whats your file extension is it `.js` or `.jsx`

Comment: Have you checked your file name and component class name `ArtistDetailsComp` is this same as `<ArtistDetails>`

Comment: Yes! They were definitely the same, but i tweaked how i was exporting and everything clicked together and worked